# Проблема с MediaPlayer

Tags: android, java

Почему появляется эта ошибка?    
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The surface has been released`

```
public class VideoPlayer extends Activity{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        Intent intent=getIntent();

        playVideo(intent.getStringExtra("position"));

    }

    public void playVideo(String nameFile) {
        try {
            SurfaceView surfaceView= (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

            mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("sdcard/Movies/video"+nameFile+".mp4");
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/surfaceView" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл в Google за 10 секунд.
[Ответ на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195512)